# how to check the return status of the store 's sync In Extjs

Tags: extjs

I use the the

```
store.sync({
   success:function(){},
   failure:function(){}
});
```

to sync with the server; when the server return {success:false} or {success:true};

how I check the json from the server in the store.sync.
I have knew that:success is called by The function to be called upon successful completion of the sync ,even if return {sucess :false} ,not only the {success:true};

Comment: Perhaps the reason why you don't get data directly in your callbacks is because there can be multiple operations performed in a single sync. So then it would be odd to return data in a delete operation for example.

Comment: Can you please check if the answer helped?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the reader's successProperty to false in the store's proxy.

```
store.proxy.reader.successProperty = false;
```

or

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    (...)
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        (...)
        reader : {
            successProperty : false,
            (...)
        }
    }
});
```

and then you can use this:

```
store.sync({
    callback : function (batch, options) {
        var operations = batch.operations;      
        for (var x in operations) {
            var operation = operations[x];
            if (operation.request) {
                console.log('operation.request ---> ', operation.request);              
            }
            if (operation.response) {
                console.log('operation.response ---> ', operation.response);                
                var object = Ext.decode(operation.response.responseText, false);
                console.log('success --->', object.success);
            }
        }       
    }
});
```